# Magento Slow. Using every trick in the book, but still slow

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

I am using this very popular theme from Themeforest. https://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864

When I try out their demos it goes pretty fast. But my own webshop, is a lot slower.

I have tried everything of "tricks" to speed Magento up. I have done most of the htaccess "tricks" I found while googling. I have cache on, compliation on, flat category on, flat product on, combined css, combined js.

When I run GTMetrix, I have 52 requests and Page Size of 2.11, but it takes 9.0s to load!!

I use a regular web-hosting, which I assumed it shared. I do not have a VPN / Dedicated server. When I contact my hosting company, they tell me it's not on their end, but that's on the template. But I see that the template is faster on the demos.

**From GTMEtrix -> Waterfall I get this**
GET category.html
200 OK
domain.com
18 KB
**5.81s** for the first GET request!? How can the first Get request be running so slow?

Answer (score 0):

If you fallback to magento core theme. Is it still slow? Basically first determine if it is simething in the theme, or something an extension is causing. So for a moment drop back to either the rwd theme or the original base theme.

Have you tried on a different hosting? Shared hosting is not usually a great place for a busy magento store to be on. You have limited resources there.

Have you checked all you logs. That is magento logs and your hosting logs. There could be issues there slowing you down.

If all of the above check out, your next step would be to profile your code.

There are many ways to do that. You can use the magento core profiler, or you could use AOE_Profiler which is a lot easier to interpret.

If you have a proper dev/test environment, you can also setup xdebug, and use the xdebug profiler to profile your load request. This will produce a cachegrind trace to which there are many tools available to parse into a human readabke format. I personally use PHPStorms built in profiler parser for this.

If you use an os that supports vagrant and docker ( i think this is now all supported cross platform?) You could also try my nifty vagrant-docker environment i use daily.

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant-docker

This will allow tou to quickly bring up a docker container version of your site. Xdebug and its profiler was just setup in this yesterday. I used it last night ( or more precise, at 2am this morning ) to profile a client site, and managed to decrease their cart load time from 10s to 1s.

The cause was very quickly identified, down to class and method using the cachegrind profile. Models in loops. The usual cause for massive performance issues.

Best of luck.